# Can echo be manipulated to write to a file in PHP

Tags: php, string, echo, fputs

I am writing a code for Sanskrit Natural Language Programming.
Earlier the machine was on test mode, so I was testing and editing from an HTML frontend to my PHP code by sending variables via GET method.

Now the code has more or less become stable.

What I want now is to write the output to a predefined txt / HTML file instead of echoing it to the browser screen.

My typical code line looks as follow:

```
if ( $a === 1 ) // if a condition is satisfied.
{ 
    //Do something here
    echo "<p class = sa >X rule has applied. </p>\n";
}
```

Is there some method by which I can manipulate the echo function and use it as -
fputs($outfile, $b); where $b is the string which is being echoed.
In the present case :

```
fputs($outfile,"<p class = sa >X rule has applied. </p>\n");
```

The code is still in a bit of development phase. So, I dont think it is a good way to replace this echo with fputs with some regex. Otherwise for a single change - I will have to make changes in both versions of code - fputs and echo one.

What made me think this is - in Python I can redefine the python functions e.g. I can define a custom function max(a,b) even if it is a built in function. I don't know any way to make my 'echo' to do work of 'fputs' in PHP.
In PHP parlance I want to do this in commandline.
e.g.

```
if (isset($argv[0])){
 // Some function to replace echo with fputs for the whole program
}
```

Any pointers to this are welcome.

Comment: Google found this rather quickly. http://codeutopia.net/blog/2007/10/03/how-to-easily-redirect-php-output-to-a-file/

Comment: Incidentally, instead of testing `$argv`, you can check the `php_sapi_name()` function, or `PHP_SAPI` constant: http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [output buffering](https://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) for this, because it lets you specify a callback function that can be used to transform the buffered data. Define a callback function which catches the buffered output and writes it to the file, while returning an empty string to the browser:

```
$outfile = fopen('log.txt', 'wb');
ob_start(function($x) use($outfile) {
    fwrite($outfile, $x);
    return '';
});
```

If you want to turn it off during the script so you can send output to the browser again, simply call [`ob_end_flush();`](https://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php).

Comment: Neat. I'd not seen `ob_start` with a callback before; I've expanded the description a bit so it's easier to understand without following the link.

Comment: You made my day. It serves my purpose. Good to learn output buffer.